# How to repeat input from the place where user put bad input?

Tags: java, try-catch

I've got some setters. The problem is that, I want to start the program from the place where user exactly put bad input.
For example: if user put bad input at `street` question it will not start from the `name` once again but from the `street`.
I know the option, but implementation is awful.

```
boolean isBadInput = true;
    while (isBadInput) {
        try {
            System.out.print("name: ");
            client.setName(input.next());
            isBadInput = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("bad input, try again");
        }
    }
    isBadInput = true;
    while (isBadInput) {
        try {
            System.out.print("surname: ");
            client.setSurname(input.next());
            isBadInput = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("bad input, try again");
        }
    }
    isBadInput = true;
    // and so on
    System.out.print("city: ");
    client.setCity(input.next());
    System.out.print("rent date: ");
    client.setRentDate(input.next());
    System.out.print("street: ");
    client.setStreet(input.next());
    System.out.print("pesel number: ");
    client.setPeselNumber(input.nextLong());
    System.out.print("house number: ");
    client.setHouseNumber(input.nextInt());
```

As you can see I need to write a lot of try/catch blocks to do it. Is there another option to make it?
I don't want to do something like this:

```
boolean isBadInput = true;
    while (isBadInput) {
        try {
            System.out.print("name: ");
            client.setName(input.next());
            System.out.print("surname: ");
            client.setSurname(input.next());
            System.out.print("city: ");
            client.setCity(input.next());
            System.out.print("rent date: ");
            client.setRentDate(input.next());
            System.out.print("street: ");
            client.setStreet(input.next());
            System.out.print("pesel number: ");
            client.setPeselNumber(input.nextLong());
            System.out.print("house number: ");
            client.setHouseNumber(input.nextInt());
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("bad input, try again");
        }
    }
```

Because program will repeat from the `name` every time.

Comment: Use a boolean flag/switch statement to find out which is not set and then use it inside the while loop

Comment: Consider renaming isBadInput to something like: isInputValid and then use false/true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the processing while/try/catch in a method :

```
public String takeInput(Scanner input, String label) {

    while (true) {
       try {
            System.out.print(label + ": ");
            return input.next();               
         } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("bad input, try again");    
            input.next();             
         }
    }
}
```

You can so do :

```
client.setname(takeInput(input, "name"));       
client.setSurname(takeInput(input, "surname"));
```

For inputs that takes other thing than String, you could introduce another method or generalize the actual takeInput() method.
You could for example generalize it in this way :

```
public <T> T takeInput(Callable<T> input, String label) {

    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(label + ": ");
            return input.call();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("bad input, try again");
            input.next();             
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("other exception...");
        }
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
Scanner input = ...;
String name = takeInput(input::next, "name");
long peselNumber = takeInput(input::nextLong, "pesel number");
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I will use the first option as it easy to understand for me. Could you tell me what `input::next` means? To concretize `::` And also `<T> T`

Comment: There might be error somewhere. If I put bad input I can't to input again, because all the time: `Try again, bad input house number: Try again, bad input house number: Try again, bad input house numbe...: ` appears

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @must you are welcome. Sure you have to consume the current input of the `Scanner` in the `catch` to pass to a new input. I updated

Comment: `input::next` is a method reference for the Callable parameter. It invokes and returns the result of `input.next()` in the context of the functional interface.

Comment: Well. I've debugged it and it seems that  loop doesn't work. Program throws `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException`.

Comment: I tested the first version and it works very well. If you don't manage to do it working you should probably open a new question as that is not related to this one.

Comment: well..I solved my problem. I think there is no need to open a new question for one small question:D I have integer takers case. In catch I put sth like this: `catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("bad input, try again");
                input.nextInt();
            }` and it caused error. Why? I had to put `input.next();` instead of `input.nextInt`. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

If your logic to check whether an input is a bad one is based on Exception, you can easily move read input part into a separate method.

```
public String readInput(Scanner scn, String label) {

    String returnValue = "";
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(label + ": ");
            returnValue  = scn.next();
            break;               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Value you entered is bad, please try again");               
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: It wont work, because I have also integers and long numbers to take.

Comment: There are few options. 
1. You can have separate methods to read different types of inputs.
2. You can read as String and parse it to required data type.
3. You can have a generalized method in above style.